# How do I enable flagged emails to show up in Outlook 2010 Tasks list

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

For a long time, flagged emails showed up in my Tasks list, and I liked this behavior.  One day, it stopped happening and I only see tasks in my list.

The problem appears to be that under "My Tasks" in the "Tasks" folder, there used to be two entries: "To-Do List" (which showed the flagged emails) and "Tasks" (which did not).  The "To-Do List" entry disappeared.

I did not make any changes to my View.  Is there a way to change my View so that I can see it again?

Comment: See if [this](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/flagged-email-messages-dont-show-in-task-list/f012db10-aec5-4901-b188-0cc323b64d9f) helps.

Comment: Definitely.  I'll post some more detail about my question with the answer that worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comment above from [Karan](https://superuser.com/users/138343/karan), I found the answer at http://www.officeforlawyers.com/outlook/tsol.htm#CLS.  I ran Outlook from the command line with the `/Resettodobar` switch and I got the "To-Do List" back.